# How to make snow

Tags: water

I want to make a DIY snowgun.

I wonder how is snow chemically made? What is the temperature needed? What is the pressure needed? What is the density of water to throw in the air? What is the humidity of the air needed? Is it easier to make with a chemical reagent?
Is there a velocity in which the water would react more efficiently? Do I need to throw the water of a certain temperature and a certain pressure directly to an atmosphere of a different temperature and different pressure?

I'm not a chemist (I'm in 12th grade) but I'm not afraid to get a complex answer that might be hard to understand.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. You should probably read about [snowflakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake) first, which would answer most of your questions.

Comment: Google 'snow cannon'. Here's a start for you  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowmaking